# Coding Bat Python Warmup

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and just starting the journey to learn how to code. I answered a problem on coding bat, however my code was different than the solution. I would appreciate if someone could tell me why my code is not as good as the solution. Thanks!

Question: Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged.

My Code:

```
    def not_string(str):
      if 'not' in str[0:3]:
        return str
      else:
        return ('not '+ str)
```

Answer:

```
    def not_string(str):
      if len(str) >= 3 and str[:3] == "not":
         return str
      return "not " + str
```

Comment: Since this is working code, would [codereview.se] be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, however, there are a couple of differences between your code and the solution. To begin with, in the solution code, they check that the length of the string is greater than or equal to 3. Using the len(str) function, it will return the number of values in that string. For instance, if I had a string of value "codingbat", the length of str would be 9. It is good practice to check the length of the str before taking further action upon it. Furthermore, the solution checks from [:3], whereas your answer checks from [0:3]; these are the same thing but it is better practice to do [:3] as it shows more professionally that it is checking the first 3 values. Lastly, you had an else statement after your first if statement which was not necessary; as long as you make sure that whatever you wanted it to do if the if statement failed, is aligned with the first if command, then they will serve the same function but it is more professional to remove the "else" and rather back indent the else command saying that if the if statement failed it would do what you wanted it to do.

Keep in mind, that in any coding language, there are several ways to reach the desired solution. Other than that, great job!

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. It helped out a lot for me to understand the key differences and why this code is much better!